# Make a player that plays Youtube videos but I don't need any iframe

Tags: jquery, youtube

I need a player that plays Youtube videos, but I don't want to use iframes. I just want a player that plays Youtube videos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<video controls="controls" 
           class="video-stream" 
           x-webkit-airplay="allow" 
           data-youtube-id="N9oxmRT2YWw"  
src="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OmxT8a9RWbE"
           ></video>
```